# NPM NODE packages for fetching proxy settings from Mac and Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, proxy, pac

Do we have any NPM NODE packages for fetching proxy settings(Could be manual and Pac) from Mac
and Linux?

For windows we have https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-proxy-settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mac: Use this NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/macos-system-proxy-settings to get the proxy settings of MAC.
Basically, it uses the command scutil --proxy.

https://dmorgan.info/posts/mac-network-proxy-terminal/

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` env var is the closest thing to a linux standard, so you should be fine with that module.

Mac is a bit harder...

Probably need to use [NodObjC](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC) or [jscocoa](https://github.com/parmanoir/jscocoa/) to access the [CFNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork) API calls like [`CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/1426754-cfnetworkcopysystemproxysettings)

Comment: Cant we use scutil --proxy command to fetch the poxy settings? is there any technical challenges when we use scutil --proxy ?